# argument of type '"counter"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: AppState) => number'

Tags: angular, ngrx

New to Angular, ngrx and TypeScript, I'm following the example on the [ngrx GitHub](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md) page to learn the basics. However, I ran into this error while following the simple app: `argument of type '"counter"' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: AppState) => number'`.

My code is below, error occurs on line 24 inside the `constructor`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { INCREMENT, DECREMENT, RESET } from './counter';

interface AppState {
    counter: number;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-counter',
    template: `
        <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
        <div>Current Count: {{counter | async}}</div>
        <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
        <button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
    `
})

export class CounterComponent {
    counter: Observable<number>;

    constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
        this.counter = store.select<number>('counter');
    }

    increment() {
        this.store.dispatch({type: INCREMENT});
    }

    decrement() {
        this.store.dispatch({type: DECREMENT});
    }

    reset(){
        this.store.dispatch({type: RESET});
    }
}
```

Am I missing some typecasting between `Observable` or `number`? Any tips would be appreciated.

**P.S. found a fix to my problem, I changed line 24 inside contructor to `this.counter = this.store.select(AppState => AppState.counter);` and everything is working fine. I'm not sure why it works yet, still trying to understand the whole thing.**

Comment: Post  your edit as the answer.. Question then shows as having an answer.. You can then accept it in due course too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a fix to my problem, I changed line 24 inside contructor to this.counter = this.store.select(AppState => AppState.counter); and everything is working fine. I'm not sure why it works yet, still trying to understand the whole thing.